# Can't resize HDD with GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to install Windows 10 after Ubuntu ([following this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/158319/641170)) and I have to resize my 1TB HDD where Ubuntu is installed but I can't resize it at all.

[image]
[image]

The problem is that it's blocked. I can't move the slider nor writing in the *new size* or *free space following* fields. I want to make a 500 GB partition.

Comment: I'm actually going to load up a Live CD and see, by the way, this is going to be temporary, is it possible to delete Windows and extend my HDD back to normal?

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question (or ask in chat)? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I did it i had to load up Live CD, sorry